# Calculating minimum bounding circle in QGIS or Python?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm attempting to calculate the radii required to cover a set of polygons in a shapefile; for example, given any number of neighborhood polygon boundaries, I'd like to calculate the smallest circle radius required to cover each.

Is there a way to calculate a minimum bounding circle in QGIS, given a polygon? Otherwise, is there a way to do so in python?

Edit: I'm using QGIS 2.18 on MacOS.

Comment: Do you have access to QGIS 3.0 (2.99)? - `Minimum bounding geometry` tool.

Comment: @Kazuhito I'm running QGIS 2.18 on MacOS. Do you know if it's possible to install 2.99? I've always used KyngChaos' ports, and the latest seems to be 2.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, only thing I can think of, with QGIS 2.18, is geometry generator.

Assuming you have convex hull polygons for each set of polygons;

```
buffer(point_on_surface($geometry), 
       max(bounds_height(bounds($geometry))/2,
           bounds_width(bounds($geometry))/2))
```

This takes maximum distance from centroid (*)  of each convex hull to create a circle.

(*) I used `point_on_surface` in lieu of `centroid`.

If you want it permanent (I mean, not only for display), please run the same expression in the Field Calculator using the *Update existing field* on  `<geometry>` column.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 3.0 (or 2.99) can calculate this directly, using either the "Minimum enclosing circles" (for a circle for each individual feature) or the "Minimum Bounding Geometry" algorithm with "geometry type" as "minimum enclosing circle" (for the entire layer at once)

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to **PostGIS** you have a function called **ST_MinimumBoundingCircle**. With SQL you can fit it to run on a single feature, several features controlled by an attribute, or on all the features of the entire layer.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html

Four demo polygons:

[image]

```
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER() AS id,
  ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(geom) As geom
FROM 
  sandbox.poly;
```

Gives one circle for each polygon:

[image]

And:

```
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER() AS id,
  type,
  ST_MinimumBoundingCircle(ST_Collect(geom)) As geom
FROM 
  sandbox.poly
GROUP BY  
  type;
```

Gives a circle based on the type attribute:

[image]

The line:

```
row_number() OVER() AS id
```

Is for QGIS to have an unique integer column for rendering the layer.

Demo made with DB Manager plugin for QGIS.